# error C2664: cannot convert 'IDWriteFactory2 **' to 'IUnknown **'

Tags: c++, directx-11

The following mwe is basically extracted from [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2D-Direct3D-Interop-ee641e46/view/SourceCode). The full example compiles and works fine, however my mwe does not compile with Visual Studio 2013 and I don't see why not.

```
#include <dwrite_2.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

using namespace std;


void main()
{
    IDWriteFactory2* m_spdwriteFactory;

    DWriteCreateFactory(
    DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
    __uuidof( IDWriteFactory2 ),
    &( m_spdwriteFactory )
    );
}
```

The error message reads:

> > ------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
>
> 1>  Source.cpp
>
> 1>Source.cpp(16): error C2664: 'HRESULT DWriteCreateFactory(DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE,const IID &,IUnknown **)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'IDWriteFactory2 **' to 'IUnknown **'
>
> 1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: The sample code uses the WRL::ComPtr<> smart pointer template class.  Which is highly recommended when you write code like this, it takes care of a lot of the boring and error-prone plumbing code you'd have to write when you use the interface pointer directly.  Including the (void**) cast you have to use to convince the compiler that you know what you are doing.  And the memory leak you created in your snippet by forgetting to call Release().

Comment: If you formulate your comment into an answer I would accept it as it states the problem and a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast m_spdwriteFactory to an IUnknown** to fix the compile error. See the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368040(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hans Passant's answer (in the comments only) was also helpful as he pointed out where my "extraction" differs from the linked example.